# Как сделать код без использования рандома?

Tags: c#

Сделал программу, которая выводит на экран двузначные числа, у которых, если к сумме единиц и десятков прибавить их квадрат, то получится то же самое число(например 90: (9+0)+(9+0)^2= 9 + 81 =90). Всего таких числа 3: 12, 42 и 90. Прошлая программа и так работала не совсем корректно, а тут ещё препод сказал переделать код без использования рандома. Думал часа 3, ни к чему не пришёл. Четвёртый раз лабу пересдаю. Помогите, пожалуйста. Вот код:

```
var random = new Random();
            int a, b, x, y, c, d;
            do
            {
                x = random.Next(1, 9);
                y = random.Next(1, 9);
            }
            while (x * 10 + y != (x + y) + Math.Pow((x + y), 2));
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{x}{y}");
                do
                {
                    a = random.Next(1, 9);
                    b = random.Next(1, 9);
                }
                while (a * 10 + b != (a + b) + Math.Pow((a + b), 2));
                if (a * 10 + b != x * 10 + y)
                Console.WriteLine($"{a}{b}");
                do
                {
                    c = random.Next(1, 9);
                    d = random.Next(1, 9);
                }
                while (c * 10 + d != (c + d) + Math.Pow((c + d), 2));
                {
                    if (c * 10 + d != a * 10 + b && c * 10 + d != x * 10 + y)
                        Console.WriteLine($"{c}{d}");
                }
                Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: А что тут вообще рандом забыл??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я не знаю, откуда родился ваш монстр, но простой перевод задачи с русского языка на C# выглядит вот так

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    for (int i = 10; i < 100; i++)
    {
        int digitSum = i / 10 + i % 10;
        if (digitSum + digitSum * digitSum == i)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Вывод в консоль

```
12
42
90
```

---

`do-while`

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int i = 10;
    do
    {
        int digitSum = i / 10 + i % 10;
        if (digitSum + digitSum * digitSum == i)
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        i++;
    } while (i < 100);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Простите, забыл уточнить. Программа должна базироваться на цикле do/while. Поражён простотой предложенного вами кода, но, к сожалению, наличие do/while в коде принципиально. Видимо, мне ещё многое предстоит понять в этой сфере

Comment: все циклы идентичны друг другу и конвертируются в конструкцию goto. конкретно for(1;2;3) { op } можно переписать через if(2) { 1; do { op; 3; } while (2); }

Comment: @Sodj готово...

Comment: Спасибо, что сделали код и объяснили. Я сегодня многому научился. Всего хорошего!